# How to set a value for each row without showing the value in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have a string array and that is what is shown on the listView; however, I want each of those rows to be assigned an int array so when it is clicked, it will subtract from the users "total_pts" and then be displayed on the totalPoints textview IF they have enough points to begin with

here is the TextView and total point variable:

```
int total_pts =0;
TextView totalPoints = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalP);
```

here is the ListView:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, redeem);

//assign to listview
list.setAdapter(adapter);

//click listener
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        //ListView Clicked item index
        int itemPosition     = position;

        int[] points = new int[]{120,150,200,200,300,400,600};

        if (total_pts >= points){
            //where I am stuck...the conditional statement won't work because I 
            //am unsure how to say the points(value) at a certain index 
            //(the index clicked) and then subtract them and then display them
            total_pts-=points;
            totalPoints.text = "Total Points: \(Total_Points)"

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: quite unclear but seems like you want `if(total_pts>=points[position]){ total_pts-=points[position]; // ..other code}`

Comment: I just refreshed android studios and used your code. It worked thank you I can mark it as correct if you leave it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `position` to fetch the value from `points` array

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // move it outside oncreate
        // no need to recreate this array everytime on click
        int[] points = new int[]{120,150,200,200,300,400,600};

        if(total_pts>=points[position]){
            total_pts-=points[position]; 
            totalPoints.setText("Total Points "+String.valueOf(total_pts));      
         }//else{ // optional 
            //totalPoints.setText("Not enough points");      
         //}
    }
});
```

Comment: @Tff Ghb i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: thank you but how would i display the points in the textview label. it says the escape key is illegal in the string literal

Comment: oh didn't notice it , you need to use `totalPoints.setText("Total Points "+String.valueOf(total_pts));`

Comment: okay so it gave me an error saying it cannot concatenate those so i tried this:
`String ptsFormat = String.format(res.getString(R.string.total_points), total_pts);
                    totalPoints.setText(ptsFormat);` and it is turning the `res` red saying qualifier must be an expression

Comment: i think it should work but try `totalPoints.setText("Total Points "+total_pts);` and also post the complete errors or `totalPoints.setText(res.getString(R.string.total_points)+total_pts);`

Comment: i figured it out i have to `Resources res = getResources();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157758/discussion-between-tff-ghb-and-pavneet-singh).